# IOS SWIFT-call code block based on uibutton image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

Here is the code I have tried to get this to work.  My goal is to call a block of code based on what the image is for the button.  The button changes image based on the previous image.

```
@IBOutlet weak var startFuncAButton: UIButton!

let navBtn = UIImage (named: "ArrowStraight")
let greenTimer = UIImage (named: "Timer")
let redTimer = UIImage (named: "TimerStop")

    @IBAction func startFuncA(sender: UIButton) {
    if self.startFuncAButton.imageView == greenTimer {
        println("button's image is green timer")
    }
    else if self.startFuncAButton.imageView == redTimer {
        println("button's image is red timer")
    }
    else if self.startFuncAButton.imageView == navBtn {
        println("button's image is arrow")
        NSLog("Start Navigation Button Pressed")
        self.navBar.hidden = true
        self.navigator = Navigator(route: self.route!)
        self.navigator?.HUD_delegate = self.navigationHUDView
        self.navigator?.locationUpdateDelegate = self
        self.navigationHUDView.hidden = false
        self.navigationHUDView.directionImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ArrowStraight")
        self.navigationHUDView.navigator = self.navigator
        self.navigationHUDView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.12, green: 0.13, blue: 0.16, alpha: 1.0)
        self.startFuncAButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Timer"), forState: .Normal)
```

But when I press this button in the app, nothing happens.  No print line is sent to the console.  Clearly, I am not doing the conditionals correctly.  How do I get it to execute code based on the image in IOS Swift?

To answer the first comment, I have expanded my code segment.  As you can see in the last line, the image is set to "Timer" and "ArrowStraight" in two lines (from the let statements).

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `greenTimer`, `redTimer`, and `navBtn` are the same exact image __instance__ that you set to the button?

Comment: I am not sure exactly how to answer your question but I have added more of my code to hopefully make things more clear.  As the code is now, there are no if statements and the arrow image appears first until it is pressed and then the timer image appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. UIButton's 'imageView' is a UIImageView. You are trying to equate it to a UIImage. They will never be the same object.
2. Relying on a button's image for executing conditional code is a very poor way of implementation. The UI (in your case the image to set) should depend on the code / logic (MVC basics). If you execute conditional code based on an image, your logic is depending on the UI.
3. You should have a flag (an enum) denoting the current state of execution.  You should set the button's image and execute the code on button tap based on the flag.

   enum TimerStatus : String {

   case Green = "Green"

   case Red = "Red"

   case Stopped = "Stopped"

   }

You can set the default status when you declare the enum variable:

```
var timerStatus : TimerStatus = .Green


switch timerStatus {
case .Green:
    // Green status code
case .Red:
    // Red status code
case .Stopped:
    // Stopped status code
}
```

Comment: I definitely do not want to do it poorly.  (1) Why is it a poor implementation (trying to learn) (2) Could you give me a small example of how this flag [enum] would work? Or point me to a tutorial or example link?

Answer (score 1):

You're testing whether or not a `UImageView` is equal to a `UIImage`. Do this instead:

```
self.startFuncAButton.imageView.image == greenTimer
```